# How I can test .net6 preview with Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sdk

I'd like to test the .Net 6 preview 3.
I downloaded and installed the SDK from [dotnet.microsoft.com](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0).
When I create a new Blazor Server project, it does not offer me the .Net 6, only version 5.
If I change the version in the csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I have yellow warnings on Dependencies-Frameworks and when I build project :
Error   NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.

How I can install in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9.3, I have Community and Enterprise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try VS 16.10.0 Preview 1.0. It's working for me. NET 6 can be used.

Comment: Thanks, I check this  [Visual Studio Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/vs/preview/)

Comment: It's also important, that you restart your computer at least once. Without restart, I couldn't use newly installed SDKs.